# Gulp task child_process.spawn curl error

Tags: node.js, curl, gulp

I'm writing a Gulp task that will execute a curl request to upload a file to an API.

Here is the request which executes as expected from the command line:

```
curl \
  -F "files[strings.pot]=@/path/to/file/i18n/strings.pot" \
  -F "json=true" \
  https://api.crowdin.com/api/project/xxxxxx/update-file?key=yyyyyy
```

Here is the task I've written so far:

```
var args = [];
args.push('-F "files[strings.pot]=@/path/to/file/i18n/strings.pot"')
args.push('-F "json=true"');
args.push('https://api.crowdin.com/api/project/'+meta.crowdin.projectIdentifier+'/update-file?key='+meta.crowdin.projectKey);

cp.spawn('curl', args, { stdio: 'inherit' })
 .on('close', function(){
    bundleLogger.end("Crowdin - Did upload POT in");
 })
 .on('exit', function(code){
    console.log('Exit code: '+code);
 });
```

This returns `curl: (26) couldn't open file "/path/to/file/i18n/strings.pot"`.

Does the child_process spawn with different permissions or $PATH or something that would cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue.

The double quotes around `"files[strings.pot]..."` were being treated as part of the filename. This works:

```
var args = [];
args.push('-F files[strings.pot]=@/path/to/file/i18n/strings.pot');
args.push('-F json=true');
args.push('https://api.crowdin.com/api/project/'+meta.crowdin.projectIdentifier+'/update-file?key='+meta.crowdin.projectKey);

cp.spawn('curl', args, { stdio: 'inherit' })
 .on('close', function(){
    bundleLogger.end("Crowdin - Did upload POT in");
 })
 .on('exit', function(code){
    console.log('Exit code: '+code);
 });
```